# chromium cannot run with www-data user

Tags: permissions, chromium, laravel

I'm using chromium on this php package https://github.com/symfony/panther

Install: `apt-get install chromium-chromedriver`

Function has been called: `$this->client = Client::createChromeClient('/usr/bin/chromedriver');`

When I deploy to Ubuntu server and run by database queue with supervisor, I use `www-data` user and received this error:

```
Could not start chrome. Exit code: 1 (General error).
Error output: cmd_run.go:1019: WARNING: cannot create user data directory: cannot create "/var/www/snap/chromium/1864": mkdir /var/www/snap: permission denied
/system.slice/cron.service is not a snap cgroup
```

Comment: Checking the user `www-data` in the /etc/passwd file it has a nologin set on it which means that it is not supposed to be used as a normal user.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, the problem was that chromedriver doesn't allow a home directory for www-data to be `/var/www`. You have to change www-data's home directory in `/etc/password` to something like `/home/www` (and remember to `mkdir`/`chmod`/`chown` that properly).

Comment: what should the permissions be?